Template File Not Found in Django
So I have been trying to serve a template file in Django. My main issue is that the index.html page is found , but the static files (js,css,png) files are not found . They are all under the same directory as index.html file. Here are my configurations :
Settings.py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
    },
]

urls.py (Main)
    path('rest-framework/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('api/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^rest-auth/',  views.obtain_auth_token),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)


urls.py (App)
urlpatterns = [
    path('homepage/', views.index, name='index'),
]

views.py
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

And here is the exact error I get:
[15/May/2024 08:31:40] "GET /api/homepage/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1837
Not Found: /api/homepage/flutter.js
[15/May/2024 08:31:40] "GET /api/homepage/flutter.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2674
Not Found: /api/homepage/manifest.json
[15/May/2024 08:31:40] "GET /api/homepage/manifest.json HTTP/1.1" 404 2683

My template files directory is like this:
accounts\
-migrations\
-templates\
server\
media\
static\
manage.py
requirements.txt

index.html
  <base href="/">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>bilmarkgorevdagilimi</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">


  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    var serviceWorkerVersion = '2027642995';
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>

How can I solve this problem?
UPDATE (for anupsabraham):
PS C:\Users\....\server> python manage.py findstatic --verbosity 2 flutter.js
No matching file found for 'flutter.js'.

Looking in the following locations:
  C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static
  C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\static

   {% load static %}
   <script src="{% static 'flutter.js' %}" defer></script>


You're probably missing the static template tag in your index.html. And the static files need to be in the static folder as mentioned in your settings.py https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files

Nope. I get the same error when I have added them to static folder and made the configuration as well. "GET /static/flutter.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1890

python manage.py findstatic --verbosity 2 flutter.js This will list the locations where django is looking for static files. Are you using python manage.py runserver command for running the application?

Check the update please. I put the output of the command you gave me. Here is also the command I run python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#std-setting-STATICFILES_DIRS
Try setting STATICFILES_DIRS in your settings.py

IT WORKED!THANKS A LOT!. Please add your comments as a proper answer so I can give you a green tick.


You must load the static template tag for Django to search for static files. link

{% load static %}
<base href="/">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'favicon.png' %}"/>

  <title>bilmarkgorevdagilimi</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="{% static 'manifest.json' %}">


  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    var serviceWorkerVersion = '2027642995';
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="{% static flutter.js %}" defer></script>


You have to define STATICFILES_DIRS in your settings.py. link

